# Convert lots of method overloads into a generic method, design question

Tags: c#, design-patterns, generics

I'm trying to refactor some code here that was done previously by other guys, since i find it quite unpractical
Here's an example

```
protected void SetParameterValue(SqlParameter parameter, string parameterValue, bool isNullable)
{
     if ((null == parameterValue || parameterValue == NULL_STRING) && isNullable)
            parameter.Value = DBNull.Value;
     else   parameter.Value = parameterValue;
}

protected void SetParameterValue(SqlParameter parameter, int parameterValue, bool isNullable)
{
     if (parameterValue == NULL_INT && isNullable)
            parameter.Value = DBNull.Value;
     else   parameter.Value = parameterValue;
}

protected void SetParameterValue( SqlParameter parameter, Int64 parameterValue, bool isNullable)
{
     if (parameterValue == NULL_LONG && isNullable)
            parameter.Value = DBNull.Value;
     else   parameter.Value = parameterValue;
}
```

Like those, there are a lot more. Now i needed to create one that accepts a new type (which doesn't have a method for it yet) and decided that maybe i could clean up a bit, make this better.
my idea is to create something like

```
protected void SetParameterValue<T>(SqlParameter parameter, T parameterValue, bool isNullable)
```

however, i don't know what's the best approach, what can i encapsulate inside this generic method and what will i need to do in separate methods as well. Is it worth it? or the "lots of methods" approach is fine? what would i gain from the generic one? thanks!

Comment: @Alex that's a little extreme

Comment: Since Nullable types are available now, you might consider dropping those NULL_INT, NULL_LONG etc. constants and just use `int?`, `long?` as the data types instead.

Comment: the problem's that the NULL_INT, etc is in a LOT of places, i want to perform some quick refactoring to make things a little bit better without having to change lots of code (and lots of retesting)

Comment: But seriously, you always set NULL when an int value is 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of removing the need for switches would be to use some kind of dictionary to hold delegates which determine what constitutes null for each possible type.  Although I think you'd have to stick with object for this.  So you'd have a dictionary and set it up like:

```
private Dictionary<Type, Func<object, bool, bool>> _nullChecks = new Dictionary<Type, Func<object, bool, bool>>();

private void SetupNullChecks(){
    _nullChecks.Add(typeof(string), (object parameterValue, bool isNullable) => { return (null == parameterValue || parameterValue.ToString() == NULL_STRING) && isNullable; });
    _nullChecks.Add(typeof(int), (object parameterValue, bool isNullable) => { return (int)parameterValue == NULL_INT && isNullable; });
    _nullChecks.Add(typeof(long), (object parameterValue, bool isNullable) => { return (long)parameterValue == NULL_LONG && isNullable; });
}
```

And your check would be like:

```
public void SetParameterValue(SqlParameter parameter, object parameterValue, bool isNullable)
{
    if (_nullChecks[parameterValue.GetType()].Invoke(parameterValue, isNullable))
        parameter.Value = DBNull.Value;
    else parameter.Value = parameterValue;
}
```

Although, as suggested by others, changing the code to use the Nullable type would be better.

Answer (score 1):

You could always do

```
Protected void SetParameterValue(SqlParameter parameter, 
 object parameterValue, bool isNullable)....
```

`parameter.Value` takes an object so minus the validation for each type, you don't really need to seperate them out.

You could create a validate parameter method which reflects and pulls type type for the parameter and checks if the null value is set against that type. 
something like

```
bool IsNull (object value){
   if (value is int){
     check int..
   }
}
//this is a quick and dirty example, there are more elegant ways to handle it.
```

This condenses your type validation and all your overloads, and it removes the need for a generic method too.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing... I'd probably also try to replace NULL_STRING, NULL_INT etc. with Nullable<T> or null where applicable.

Comment: i don't find it a good practice to pass around "object" types, and there's lot of boxing/unboxing. isn't there something with generics that can accomplish the same thing, but without having to create a giant switch statement with each type?

Comment: Well you're still going to box because parameter.Value takes an object.

Comment: The conditional statement is going to be difficult to get around, because you are eventually going to have to ask the "What type is this object?" and when you get the answer, you have enact certain validation rules.  It all comes down to if this is X, then do this.  It just all depends on where you are going to ask the question, in your example, your still doing it, you've just separated out the logic between methods.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use nullable types instead of bool isNullable.

```
protected void SetParameterValue<T>(SqlParameter parameter, T parameterValue)
{
if (parameterValue == null)
  parameter.Value = DBNull.Value;
else
  parameter.Value = parameterValue;
}
```

And possibly call it accordingly with this signature.
Like 
SetParameter(param,null)
SetParameter(param,5)

Comment: You are not addressing the fact that value types cannot be null.

Comment: Wait a second, you mean SetParameter<int?>(param,null) won't work?

Comment: yes, but SetParameter<int> won't.  Since value types can't be null parameterValue == null will always be false.

Comment: @Kevin well, but in this case int parameter won't be equal to  NULL_INT (in question)

Comment: @jenea, except that isn't in your validation logic,  someone can still do SetParameterValue<int>.... and validate a null value to true.  It doesn't matter that there are other options to add an int value.  The generic method provided allows that to occur.

Answer (score 0):

The 'multiple signatures' approach to method definition is perfectly fine - it's what gives us polymorphism. Personally, I'd prefer to keep that technique rather than refactor as you suggest.

However, what I *would* do is replace the repetition of the method body in all but one with calls to the 'master' method, casting the parameter thus:

```
protected void SetParameterValue(SqlParameter parameter, int parameterValue, bool isNullable)
{
  SetParameterValue(parameter, (Int64)parameterValue, isNullable);
}
protected void SetParameterValue(SqlParameter parameter, Int64 parameterValue, bool isNullable)
{
  if (parameterValue == NULL_INT && isNullable)
    parameter.Value = DBNull.Value;
  else
    parameter.Value = parameterValue;
}
```

This presupposes that `parameterValue` can be re-cast without too much hassle, of course.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to "remove" the question with switch/if statments in the end, someone have to do it.
You have the option of override/encapsulate what is null for an object or a class, but you'll still have to check what is null in each concept.

I don't know if this make things better, but you can first isolate the repetition by creating a method as said before or  isolate only the nulls checking. The last one is what I did bellow:

```
protected void SetParameterValue(SqlParameter parameter,object parameterValue){
    if(IsParameterNull(parameterValue) && parameter.IsNullable){
        parameter.Value = DBNull.Value;
    }
    else{
        parameter.Value = parameterValue;
    }
}

List<NULLTYPE> nulls = new List<NULLTYPE>(){new NULLTYPE(NULL_INT), new NULLTYPE(NULL_LONG), new NULLTYPE(null)}
protected bool IsParameterNull(object parameterValue){
    if(nulls.Contains(parameterValue)) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

The job here is to create a `NULLTYPE` class that encapsulates your concepts of null and them the `nulls.Contains(parameterValue)` checks if the value exists in the list. 
You can go further and override `Contains` to check on your own way, but you have to think how much work do you want to spend on this.

Comment: Another thing that I forgot to say is that if you really want to code a good code start by reading Clean Code http://tinyurl.com/3xyq2ob. It's not a bible and I'm not an evangelist, but it'll open your mind or at least help a little =D

Comment: This seems like an interesting solution, although I'm not sure I understand what the NULLTYPE class looks like.  How does List.Contains() work when comparing an Object to a NULLTYPE?  Casting operators? And how does it take into account things like checking if a (non-value type) is actually null?  Don't you at some point just end up with a switch statement in NULLTYPE anyway?

Comment: Unfortunatelly in somewhere at some point we will end up with either a reconstruction of types and its meanings of nulls or a switch statement. That is why I told this is a question on how much work do you want to put on it. 
NullType class depends on the developer desires, it could be as simple as:

Comment: public NullType{
  protected object nullValue;
  public NullType(object nullValue){
     this.nullValue = nullValue;
  }
}
Following this idea the List.Contains() method is only checking if the parameterValue is "equals" to a NULLTYPE. And yeah he is casting operators, it's very difficult (not impossible) to get away from casting, swicthing or anything like this without re-create your types to tell them what is to be null and even further to do this receiving generic values.

Comment: By the way I liked your solution, I read it just before I answered your comment here.